# How to come up with SELECT queries?

Tags: 8, database

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field_name FROM table_name
```

I tried:

```
\Drupal::database()->select('table_name', 't');
$query->fields('t', ['field_name']);
$result = $query->execute();
```

But since `Connection::select` expects base table this did not work.

How am I supposed to execute it? I used entityQuery previously. I could not find a way to filter out the unique values of only one field using entityQuery.

**Note**: I went through [this example](https://www.codeexpertz.com/blog/drupal/drupal-8-how-use-select-query-syntax-and-example) which is basically using `Connection::select`. But `Connection::select` requires to provide the base table. In entityQuery (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.2.x) I did not have to provide the base table data.

Comment: Hey hey, please add what you tried to give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Did you already have a look at [Connection::select](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Connection.php/function/Connection%3A%3Aselect/8.2.x)?

Comment: https://www.codeexpertz.com/blog/drupal/drupal-8-how-use-select-query-syntax-and-example
I went through this example which is basically using Connection::select. But Connection::select requires to provide the base table. In entityQuery (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.2.x) I did not have to provide the base table data.

Comment: "But since Connection::select expects base table this did not work." - what?

Comment: Forget that random blog post. What code are you actually trying?

Answer (score 3):

The Problem is, that you need to fetch the results from your execution.

Your code should look like this:

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('table_name', 't');
$query->fields('t', ['field_name']);
$query->distinct();
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

That does the same as the query you stated above.
Alternatively you can fetch your results with a complete custom query:

```
$result = Drupal::database()->query('SELECT DISTINCT field_name FROM table_name')->fetchAll();
```

Notice here that you dont have to `execute()` your query in this case. Instead you can directly fetch your results.
You will still need the `execute()` for insert/update or similiar queries.